# Flutter showing only 0-9 keypad instead of extended number keypad when using text input (i.e. all ascii characters should be available)

Tags: ios, flutter

In my flutter app, I cannot get the full numeric keypad (0-9 + "top row" characters like !,@,# etc) to appear, even when using

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.text
```

I've included screenshots below of what I want vs. what I get.

> **When I open the keyboard in flutter in iOS**

[image]

> **I Get This**

[image]

> **But I Want This**

[image]

> **This is my code**

```
TextField(
            key: key,
            style: textStyle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            controller: textFieldController,
            cursorColor: selectedColor,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: onChanged )
```

Comment: Hi! I tried to reproduce your scenario. However, I the num keyboard is the full-extend (the one you want to appear). I'm using Flutter 1.17.5 and emulation in an iPhone SE (2nd gen). Which ones are you using?

Comment: @BlasOrtellado looks like upgrading to 1.17.5 fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to run the app without specifying the keyboardtype. When I recreated the text field and specified the keyboardtype to textinputtype.text, I also got the same output, but when I ran the app without specifying the keyboardtype my keyboard was fine. This is my first contribution, so please let me know if it fixed the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get it you can set keyboardType

for example

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true)
```

this will give this look

[image]